# Error:(52, 25) java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

Можете помочь, пожалуйста. Я не знаю, как изменить код, чтобы не было этой ошибки. При этом не надо использовать mutable объекты.

```
public class Lab8 {
    class Device {
        String name;
        String model;
        String year;

        public String getName(){ return name; }
        public String getModel(){ return model; }
        public String getYear(){ return year; }

        public Device(String name, String model, String year){
            this.name=name;
            this.model=model;
            this.year=year;

        }

        public void display(){
            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Model: " + model);
            System.out.println("Year: " + year);
        }
    }

    class Laptop extends Device{
        public Laptop(String name, String model, String year) {
            super(name, model, year);
        }
    }

    class Tablet extends Device{
        public Tablet(String name, String model, String year) {
            super(name, model, year);
        }
        @Override
        public void display(){
            System.out.printf("Name -> :) %s \n", getName());
            System.out.printf("Model -> :) %s \n", getModel());
            System.out.printf("Year -> :) %s \n", getYear());
        }
    }

    class PC extends Device {
        public PC(String name, String model, String year) {
            super(name, model, year);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Laptop Laptop = new Laptop("Laptop", "ASUS", "2018");
        Laptop.display();
        Tablet Tablet = new Tablet("Tablet", "SONY", "2010");
        Tablet.display();
        PC PC = new PC("PC", "HP", "2017");
        PC.display();

    }

}
```

Comment: В общем или пишите `static class Device` или вынесите его из-под `class Lab8`. Гуглить по ключевому слову `inner class`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вся проблема заключается в том, что в одном классе у вас есть метод `main`, и поля класса. Если вы хотите, чтобы операции происходили в одном классе/фале, то поля класса следует обозначать как её `static`. 
Другое решение проблемы - это создать отдельный класс только с методом `main`, где и проводить все операции, а из Lab8 `main` удалить.